# How to optimize single query to be called multiple time in LINQ Instantly?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am calling single query to get multiple categories data on the homepage of my web application using Ajax. But its performance sucks. How to improve it?

```
var result = _db.news.Where(a => a.Sector == sector)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.ModifiedOn)
    .Select(a => new LatestNewsView { 
        Id = a.Id, 
        Title = a.Title, 
        CreatedOn = a.ModifiedOn, 
        ImageUrl = a.ImageUrl, 
        Sector = a.SubTitle, 
        Country = a.Country, 
        NewId = a.NewsId 
    })
    .AsNoTracking().Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({ url: "/Home/NewsBySectorTitle?sector=10, dataType: "html" }).done(function (data) {$("#col1").append(data);});
```

Comment: You are calling the same query multiple times?

Comment: Nothing stands out as obviously wrong. This type of question is virtually unanswerable. We can't profile your application. We don't know indexes, query plans. Etc. etc.

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Yes m calling same function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slowness can come from the following sources:

- database
- application server
- application
- server-side network
- response size
- internet connection
- browser

#### Database

You will need to run the query generated by LINQ directly in the database. If it is slow, then you have a database-level performance issue. In this case you will need to take a look at the schema of the database, the size of the table(s) involved and the query itself. It is evident that you have a filter by `Sector`. Do you have an index on this field? If no, it would not hurt to create one. That will increase the speed of reading operations, but decrease the speed of the writing operations, due to the fact that the index will be calculated. However, reads are usually much more frequent than writes. Take a look at the columns being loaded as well. Is any of the columns containing long texts of big data?

#### Application server

Is your IIS set up to handle requests sequentially? Are other sites running on the same server?

#### Application

You will need to put a breakpoint there to make sure this is indeed the operation which takes a long time. If this is the case, then it is most probably a database issue, but not necessarily. If, for instance you execute this a lot of time,s. If this is not as slow as you think is, the slowness might come from another place in the application. Another query perhaps, or, if you are executing this query many times, you might need to modify the query to load batches of data.

#### Server-side network

You might want to check the network server-side. If a message in general is slow to arrive from the router to the server and back, then this might be the cause of your specific case as well.

#### Response size

It is possible that `take` is very large or you have a long text in each row and the data takes a lot of time to be downloaded. In this case you might want to sent the first 10 results initially and load the rest while the user is looking at the first 10.

#### Internet connection

If your or your server's internet connection is very slow, that could be a not programming-related cause of your issue as well.

#### Browser

You are appending the data via jquery. If you replace that with `console.log('foo');` is the performance improving a lot? In this case your structure might be very complicated with a lot of events, causing your browser to load things forever.